# ODBC Driver Manager not found .. Connect MSAccess with Java?

Tags: java, database, odbc

This problem appears to me when I run the program
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uCDX.png]

From `Control Panel > Administrative Tools > ODBC Data Source (64-bit)
User DSN not contain MSAccess`

not possible to add Access driver ..
[image: http://im74.gulfup.com/aUnu7p.png]

Please How can Solve this problem and thanks you ..

Here is my code.

```
public class Main 
{
    private static final String MyDataBase = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBO=C:\\Users\\samer\\workspace\\DS2\\DB\\DS2.mdb;";      
    private static Connection conn = null;
    private static Statement stat = null ;

    public Main() 
    {
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(MyDataBase);
            stat = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "insert into Employee values (1001,'10011001')";
            stat.execute(sql);    
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "correct insert");
        } 
        catch (SQLException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Sorry1 ,  Try again !!");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e2) 
        {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Sorry2 ,  Try again !!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make sure that your bit depthness is the same at all points, x64 Java, x64 Access driver, x64 bit Access (or 32but across the board). It's been a while since I played with Access, but you should ensure that Access is installed (I think you can install the drivers, but it's been a while)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that driver is going away (it is not in Java 8).

I've been using a JDBC solution called UCanAccess within Java, and it's been working quite well for me.

http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html